# Passing database table name into another page

Tags: php, database-table

Im trying to pass the value of the database table name to another page.

I succesfully display all the database table from my database but the problem is that Im trying to pass it to another page when I click the database table name so that I can get all the values of that table.

```
<div>
      <span class="list-group-item active">
        Category
      </span>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <?php
          $user = "id6520034_id6520034_shoppingbaguser2"; 
          $password = "travelcompanion17012"; 
          $host = "localhost";



          $connection= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password); 

          if (!$connection)
            {
              die ('Could not connect:' . mysqli_error());
            }

          $showtables= mysqli_query($connection,"SHOW TABLES FROM id6520034_id6520034_shoppingbag2");
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($showtables)) {
        ?>

        <a href="./view-all.php?'.$row[productID].'" class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">14</span>
          <?php echo "$row[0]"; ?>
        </a>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The href link is not working it wont send the value of the database table name to another page.

Hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: The $row[productID] part in the anchor tag is not inside any <?php ... ?> tags.

Comment: Syntax error at the `<a>` tag. You can easily debug by reviewing the resultant HTML source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a number of issues in the code.

First is

```
"SHOW TABLES FROM id6520034_id6520034_shoppingbag2"
```

will return a list of table names not a key/value pair

Second is as you are using mysqli_fetch_row in your code as follows

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($showtables)) {
```

the $row[0] element will carry the table name. You cannot use a key like $row['productID']

Third is you have mixed php and html here. Also you are missing a parameter name

```
href="./view-all.php?'.$row[productID].'"
```

You should rewrite something like

```
href="./view-all.php?tablename=<?php echo $row[0];?>"
```

Comment: The query should be `SELECT * FROM id6520034_id6520034_shoppingbag2`. Paging can be added to enhance performance.

Comment: Well, he is trying to query the list of tables in the database.